# I can't Disable the Arrow up/arrow down in Textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following jQuery:

```
$("#message").keyup(function(e) {
    if ((e.keyCode === 40) || (e.keyCode === 38)) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

So when I type something in and I should press arrow up or down, it should not work. But instead of that functionality not working, the script is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `keydown` for that:

```
$("#message").keydown(function(e) {
    if ((e.keyCode === 40) || (e.keyCode === 38)) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Write it in document ready state

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#message").keyup(function(e) {
        if ((e.keyCode=== 40) || (e.keyCode=== 38)) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[JSBIN](https://jsbin.com/noyegisugi/edit?html,js,output)

Use `Keydown`

```
$("#message").keydown(function(e) {
    if ((e.keyCode === 40) || (e.keyCode === 38)) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

In javascript you can use

```
  <textarea rows = 10 cols =10 id="message" onkeydown="testData()"></textarea>

function testData(){
  var x = event.which || event.keyCode; 
  if(x == 40 || x== 38){
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}
```